# Python List : Index out of Range

Tags: python

I've been trying to create a program that has to read in a file, find the unique words and punctuation, put those to a list and then get the positions of each word and store them in a list. Then, using the lists the program will recreate the file. This is my code:

```
import time
import re
words = open('words.txt')
sentence = words.read()
uniquewords = []
positions = []
punctuation = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sentence)
for word in punctuation:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)
print("This file contains the words and punctuation ", uniquewords)
positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in punctuation]
recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])
print("In a list the text file words.txt can be shown as:")
print(positions)
print("Recreating sentence...")
print(recreated)
```

The program above does what it needs to, except it produces the following output:

> This file contains the words and punctuation  ['Ask', 'not', 'what',
>   'your', 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you', ',', '!']
>
> In a list the
>   text file words.txt can be shown as:
>
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 8, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 10]
>
> Recreating sentence...
>
> Ask not what your country can do for you , Ask what you can do for
>   your country !

The positions list starts at 0, so as normal I tried just doing this:

```
positions = [uniquewords.index(word)+1 for word in punctuation]
```

However this produces the error

```
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\COMPUTING TEMP FOLDER\task 3.py", line 13, in <module>
    recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\COMPUTING TEMP FOLDER\task 3.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**How can I make the list start at 1 without getting this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Another small problem is that while the original string is

"Ask not what your country can do for you, Ask what you can do for
your country!"

the actual output is instead

Ask not what your country can do for you , Ask what you can do for your country !

Comment: Do you know what format to expect from the input file?

Comment: The code you posted suggesting it raises an error is not the same code as in the traceback. You should probably update that. Your last question about the extra spaces is because every word (or punctuation mark) is surrounded by spaces because of your `str.join`. You will have to do that differently. Also, why are you trying to reindex the list to start at one? I didn't really understand that.

Comment: @FamousJameous How would you suggest doing it differently?

Comment: @finnadie123 Which part? If the problem in the last section is really about extra spaces, I see no way of doing what you want using `join`. I would probably keep separate lists for words and punctuation and then iterate over positions and handle words and punctuation separately. For the reindexing thing, I wouldn't do the reindexing. I still don't see why you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are incrementing every element of `positions` so that it displays as 1-indexed, then using that array when python is expecting 0-indexed. Try using:

```
recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i-1] for i in positions])
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code. I changed bit for recreating string to solve space issue along with the indexing problem you were facing.

```
import time
import re
words = open("val.txt",'r')
sentence = words.readline()
uniquewords = []
positions = []
punctuation = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sentence)
for word in punctuation:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)
print("This file contains the words and punctuation ", uniquewords)
positions = [uniquewords.index(word)+1 for word in punctuation]
#recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i-1] for i in positions])
recreated = ''
for i in positions:
     w = uniquewords[i-1]
     if w not in '.,!?;':
          w = ' ' + w
     recreated = (recreated + w).strip()

print("In a list the text file words.txt can be shown as:")
print(positions)
print("Recreating sentence...")
print(recreated)
```

Output:

```
    C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
('This file contains the words and punctuation ', ['Ask', 'not', 'what', 'your',
 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you', ',', '!'])
In a list the text file words.txt can be shown as:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 11]
Recreating sentence...
Ask not what your country can do for you, Ask what you can do for your country!
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Updated the code. There were two problems 1) Related to indexing and 2) Related to quotes missing in final output. Initially I missed first part.

Comment: @DineshPundkar apologies I don't know why I put quotes on the original string, the actual problem is the spaces with the punctuation.

Comment: @finnadie123 - Please check the updated code in answer. As per your last comment, double quote is not necessary so I removed that part from regex. Also, did change in recreating line code to solve spaces with the punctuation problem

Comment: @finnadie123 - Does above code change works for you?